# Menu Lateral fazendo chamada com Angular!

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Pessoal tenho um menu e preciso que ao clicar em um link ele apareça um conteúdo, e ao clicar em outro link ele esconda o conteúdo anterior e exiba o novo conteúdo selecionado, estou usando Angular 1 por particularidade do projeto.. tenho o seguinte código porem não sei como esconder um conteúdo quando outro é acionado. Agradeço!

```
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">&nbsp</span>
    <a ng-click="vm.link1 = true">
        Link 1
    </a>
</li> 

<section id="mainContent" class="col-md-9"
    ng-if="vm.link1">
    content 1
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Já resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">&nbsp</span>
    <a ng-click="vm.link = 'link1'">
        Link 1
    </a>
</li>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">&nbsp</span>
    <a ng-click="vm.link = 'link2'">
        Link 2
    </a>
</li> 

<section id="mainContent" class="col-md-9"
    ng-if="vm.link == 'link1'">
    content 1
</section>
<section id="mainContent" class="col-md-9"
    ng-if="vm.link == 'link2'">
    content 2
</section>
```

Agradeço!

Comment: Não sei se o ng-if  aceita css customizado, caso você precise de fazer efeitos te aconselho a usar o ng-show ou ng-hide link da documentação: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Ok, obrigado vou dar uma olhada!